# Run testNG tests based on "priority" of test cases

Tags: eclipse, automated-tests, testng

Is it possible to run TesNG tests based on priority? For example, say I want to run only the tests which have `priority=1`.

```
<testng outputDir="${report.dir}" haltOnFailure="true" groups="${groups}">

    <!-- Extra project classpath-->
    <!-- Tell Ant where is the project and test classes -->
   <classpath refid="selenium.classpath" />
   <classpath refid="dynamicreports.classpath" />   


    <!-- Tell Ant what test classes need to run -->
    <classfileset dir="${bin.dir}" includes="**/*.class" />

</testng>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using BeanShell script in TestNG XML suite definition. Something like:

```
<method-selector>
    <script language="beanshell">
        <![CDATA[ testngMethod.getPriority() > 1 ]]>
    </script>
</method-selector>
```

See http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#beanshell for more details.

Comment: Thanks Jaroslav,but i am not using testng.xml .i am running the classes containing the testng methods using Ant's "testng" task.Here is the sample   code.

Comment: <testng outputDir="${report.dir}" haltOnFailure="true" groups="${groups}">
   
    <!-- Extra project classpath-->
    <!-- Tell Ant where is the project and test classes -->
      <classpath refid="selenium.classpath" />
      <classpath refid="dynamicreports.classpath" /> 
  
   
    <!-- Tell Ant what test classes need to run -->
    <classfileset dir="${bin.dir}" includes="**/*.class" />
   
   </testng>

Comment: pls let me know is it possible to do it without testng.xml

Comment: It's probably not possible because ant task doesn't support this setting. But you can pass testng.xml file via ant parameter `xmlPathInJar` so you can create more xml files in your project (like priority1.xml, priority2.xml, ...) and then use `xmlPathInJar` instead of `groups`.

Answer (score 1):

You can have Groups to do this for you . Assign a group to the testcase according to the priority and run only that group

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups

Comment: Thanks for the help Gosaka,but i  want to know whether it is possible to make use of priority attribute in[@Test(priority=1,groups={"functional"})] without mentioning it in the groups